# locations property in PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer class

Tags: java, spring

Whenever we want to inject a list of properties file, we put the below code block in our xml:

```
<beans:bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="locations">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>abc.properties</beans:value>
            <beans:value>pqr.properties</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

However when I see the source code of class PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, I do not see any list property named "locations".

Why is that so ?

How actually does it work ?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the [`PropertiesLoaderSupport`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PropertiesLoaderSupport.html#setLocations(org.springframework.core.io.Resource[])) which [`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) inherits from.

[image: PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer]

<sup>Where's Wally?</sup>